# Laravel Eloquent belongsToMany

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have three db tables:

```
attributes
---------------------------------
| id | name | showed_name | class

attributes_profiles
----------------------------------------------
| id | attribute_name | profile_id | content |

profiles
------------
| id | ... |
```

When a User go on the profile site, I want to load ALL Attributes from the table, but I also want the content from the intermediate table (pivot) for this user (id).

```
public function Attribute(){
  return $this->belongstoMany('App\Attribute', 'attributes_profiles', 'profile_id', 'attribute_name','id','name')->withPivot('content');
}
```

With this class in the profiles model, I wouldn't be able to get all attributes.

When I use a Profiles() Class in the Attributes Model, I get every Attribute but not the content for the user... but for every user.

Comment: Not sure what you're doing with that `belongsToMany()`; it has a max of 4 attributes: `belongsToMany('Model', 'table', 'local_key', 'foreign_key');`: *"The third argument is the foreign key name of the model on which you are defining the relationship, while the fourth argument is the foreign key name of the model that you are joining to:"*

Answer (score 0):

When you use a [Many-to-many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many), you can access the intermediate table with the `pivot` attribute. I see you already have the `withPivot` directive in the relationship, so you are ready to go.

```
foreach($profile->attribute as $attribute) {
  $attribute->pivot->content; // The content in the intermediate table
}
```